# TYPO3: Backend Module

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I've installed the [lfeditor](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/lfeditor) extension, the backend module is registered as per below (`ext_tables.php`):

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
    'SGalinski.lfeditor',
    'user',
    ...
```

In other words, the backend module is registered as a submodule of the user main module.

I can't seem to be able to find the backend module though. Changing the second parameter to `'web'` results in the link showing up under *Web*, but of course I don't want to change the original code.

How do I activate the user main module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User menu was moved to the top bar, so modules added to it will be availble there ;) Right, this one should be probably be placed in other menu (System?), but I think that's an author's concept.

[image: here you are]

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate one of the "User" extension, for example "User>User Settings". If you activate it, menu "USER TOOLS" should be visible.